# Unable to connect to SQL server on localhost

Tags: java, sqlite

i just keep getting Connection Failed, i dont know why, im running a server on UniServerZ and trying to get the SQL file from localhost.

Im using uniserverZ (Unicontroller.exe) and i made the .sqlite file using SQLite manager addon for firefox. Anyone can help me out here? Thanks!

Edit: Ok, now im just trying to load the sqlite file from my C drive, i have commented out the command that would load it from my localhost because it doesnt work either. Any help?

```
package ui;
import java.sql.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class MySQLConnect {
        Connection conn=null;
        public static Connection ConnectDb(){

            try{
                Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
                 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\UniServerZ\\home\\Database\\db");

//               Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql:\\localhost:3306\\Database\\db\\student.sql","root","root");

                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Successful!");
                return conn;
            } catch(Exception e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connection Failed");
                return null;
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: Can you post `e.printStackTrace();`?

Comment: Are you sure about where is your SqlLite db file? Do your code have an access to it? Your patch for SqlLite looks strange for me. SqlLite have an form of one file i thought. Are you sure that you have library on the classpatch to the SQL lite driver?

Comment: Why is everything called "MySQL"? And what is the actual path of the database file?

Comment: Does sqlite allow for network connections?

Comment: I can only set connections like jdbc:sqlite:C:/work/product.db

Answer (score 0):

This connection is strange

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306//Database//student.sql
```

try

```
"jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Database",userName,password
```

where Database is the real data base name.

Note also single `/` vs `//`

Answer (score 0):

You work with Sqlite database but used the jar of Mysql..

So correct this line.

```
String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
```

to

```
String driver = "org.sqlite.JDBC";
```

Change url and add the sqlite jdbc driver to succesfull connection  with Sqlite DB.

And remove one `/` from below line after . `jdbc:sqlite:` need only `/` .

```
 Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite://localhost/Database/db/database.sqlite");
```

Thanks..